# How to send trigger event and know if it was cancelled/consumed by any recipient?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a custom navigation system, where the anchor links are store in parent items as `data-url =` attributes. This way the entire item is clickable (among other features).

I need the default behaviour of these child items to be to process the links normally (i.e. change window.location).

**Q: How can I signal back from `trigger`ed recipients that the message was consumed so *do not proceed with "normal processing"*?** Or possibly just *how do you get at the event object the trigger passes around?*

### Sample JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/dXkbW/6/

```
// Construct the test structure
var $panel = $('.panel');
var $items = $panel.find('li:has(a)');
$items.each(function () {
    var $item = $(this);
    $item.addClass('item');
    var $a = $item.find('a[href]');
    $item.attr('data-url', $a.attr('href')).attr('data-target', $a.attr('target'));
    $a.contents().unwrap();
});

// Test click handler
$panel.on('click', '.item', function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    //alert($this.attr('data-url'));
    $this.trigger('navigate', [$this.attr('data-url'), $this.attr('data-target')]);

    // Q: How to know if a receiving item consumed the click???
    if ("some test goes here"){
        // Navigate like normal link
        window.location = $this.attr('data-url');
    }
});

// Test parent control click handler
// e.g. only wants events targetted at ".content"
$(document).on('navigate', function(e, url, target){
    alert(" url='" + url + "' target= \'" + target + "'");
    // Process .content targetted links here and not at source
    if (target == '.content'){
        e.preventDefault();   // or something else?
    }
});
```

### Sample HTML

```
<div class="panel">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="link1.html" target=".content">Link1</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="link2.html" target=".other1">Link1</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="panel">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="link3.html" target=".content">Link1</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="link4.html" target=".other1">Link1</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="other"></div>
```

I would like to use something standard like `e.preventdefault()`, but how do you access the event object from where you call `trigger`?

Comment: How about making a trigger inside the `document.on('navigate')` event. Then instead of `"some test goes here"` you can have another `.on` listener and know if it was clicked. Or use a more specialized event library if you do not want to work with jQuery.

Comment: @DrColossos: Adding another handler would lose the current code position, so requiring more code, not a good option. Turns out you can just create a jQuery event object and pass/use that with `trigger` (see answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Documentation... Argh!

It actually turns out to be reasonably simple but is only mentioned on this page http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ and not on `trigger` reference page:

**"Create an event object yourself and pass it to trigger!"** :)

```
var e = jQuery.Event( "navigate" );
$this.trigger(e, [$this.attr('data-url'), $this.attr('data-target')]);

if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    // Someone prevented the default event!
    alert('Prevented!');
}
else
{
    alert('Navigated!');
    // Navigate like normal link
    //window.location = $this.attr('data-url');
}
```

### Improved version:

You can also simply extend the jQuery event object (instead of passing parameters).

```
var e = jQuery.Event( "navigate", {url: $this.attr('data-url'), navtarget: $this.attr('data-target')} );
$this.trigger(e);
```

and reference custom event parameters instead:

```
$(document).on('navigate', function (e) {
    alert(" url='" + e.url + "' target= \'" + e.navtarget + "'");
    // Process .content targetted links here and not at source
    if (e.navtarget == '.content') {
        e.preventDefault(); // or something else?
    }
});
```

Much nicer and now looks like it was *built in*. You just have to avoid any existing property names (I used `target` as a custom before I realized it was an existing, *rather important* property) :)